# Date for VBA not working in Excel 2011?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

Here is my code, I am attempting, which works BTW on a PC, but not on a Mac, to run this code and have an excel sheet created, named, add a tab, change the color of said tabs, change the name of said tabs, and then transpose the data while maintaining the format of the cells and width and height of the cells to the new worksheet.

This works, on a PC.... but when I get onto a Mac, it doesn't.

I go into References, and this is what I see.

[image]

I see Ref Edit Control, and Microsoft Scripting Runtime are missing. I disabled both, and the script gives me an error here still:

```
wbBK2.SaveAs Dir & Application.PathSeparator & "Open Order Report -" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"
```

The error happens at the `(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")` Specifically the **Date** section. I can't figure out why this is happening honestly. If someone can peruse this and give me an answer and a solution it be greatly appreciated.

The error I get is an `Error '9 Subscript Out Of Range` I can't see a reason why this error only shows up on a Mac, and not a PC.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenOrderReportExport()

    Dim wsJL As Worksheet   'Jobs List
    Dim wsPOT As Worksheet  'PO Tracking
    Dim wsTNO As Worksheet  'Tel-Nexx OOR
    Dim wsDOO As Worksheet  'Dakota OOR
    Dim wbBK1 As Workbook   'Open Order Report
    Dim wbBK2 As Workbook   'New Workbook
    Dim wsWS1 As Worksheet  'Sheet1
    Dim wsWS2 As Worksheet  'Sheet2
    Dim wsWS3 As Worksheet  'Sheet3
    Dim wsWS4 As Worksheet  'Sheet4
    Dim CurrentFile As String, NewFileType As String, NewFile As String, Dir As String, lastrow As Long

    Set wsJL = Sheets("Jobs List")      'Jobs List
    Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")   'PO Tracking
    Set wsTNO = Sheets("Tel-Nexx OOR")  'Tel-Nexx OOR
    Set wsDOO = Sheets("Dakota OOR")    'Dakota OOR
    Set wbBK1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbBK2 = Workbooks.Add           'New Workbook
    Set wsWS1 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Sheet1
    Set wsWS2 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet2")  'Sheet2
    Set wsWS3 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet3")  'Sheet3


        Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.
        CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        NewFileType = "Excel Files 2007 (*.xlsx)"
        Dir = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & "Reports"
        wbBK2.SaveAs Dir & Application.PathSeparator & "Open Order Report -" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Set wsWS4 = wbBK2.Sheets("Sheet4")  'Sheet4

        With wbBK2
            Dim Sht As Worksheet
                For Each Sht In Worksheets
                    Sht.Tab.Color = 255
                Next
        End With

        Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Jobs List"
        Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "PO Tracking"
        Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Dakota OOR"
        Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Tel-Nexx OOR"

        With wbBK1
            'Jobs List Export
            lastrow = wsJL.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsJL.Range("A2:N2").Copy
            wsWS1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            wsJL.Range("A3:N" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wsWS1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            wsJL.Range("B3:N" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS1.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            wsWS1.Columns("A").Delete

            'Tel-Nexx Export
            lastrow = wsTNO.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsTNO.Range("A2:Q2").Copy
            wsWS2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            wsTNO.Range("A3:Q" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wsWS2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            wsTNO.Range("B3:Q" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS2.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            wsWS2.Columns("A").Delete

            'Dakota Export
            lastrow = wsDOO.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsDOO.Range("A2:O2").Copy
            wsWS3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            wsDOO.Range("A3:O" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS3.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wsWS3.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            wsDOO.Range("B3:O" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS3.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            wsWS3.Columns("A").Delete

            'PO Tracking Export
            lastrow = wsPOT.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsPOT.Range("A2:K2").Copy
            wsWS4.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            wsPOT.Range("A3:K" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS4.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wsWS4.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            wsPOT.Range("B3:K" & lastrow).Copy
            wsWS4.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            wsWS4.Columns("A").Delete
        End With

        With wsWS1
            .Activate
            .Range("A1").Select
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Dlls are for Windows. They should not work on a Mac without doing some sort of work-around, like virtualization. However, I do not see anything in your code that on first glance requires either of those dlls. Try removing the references, and see if your code works.

Comment: Nope, Error Type 9, looks like the document is created, but not named or saved. So same place, just not really descriptive of why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **MISSING** references are what are causing the problems. Remove the checkmarks there, and the basic stuff like `date` will start working again. If those references are critical to the code you are running, you will have to search out the Mac equivalents

More about references - normally resolving "Missing" fixes it, but, from [here](http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-63738.html)

What you're describing is typical of corrupted references. This can
be caused by a referenced file being a different version or in a different
location between the machine on which the code was developed, and the
client machines. Our company also tries to keep all the machines configured
the same way, but I've found it's essentially impossible to manage.

Open any code module (or open the Debug Window, using Ctrl-G, provided you
haven't selected the "keep debug window on top" option). Select Tools |
References from the menu bar. Examine all of the selected references.

If any of the selected references have "MISSING:" in front of them, unselect
them, and back out of the dialog. If you really need the reference(s) you
just unselected (you can tell by doing a Compile All Modules), go back in
and reselect them.

If none have "MISSING:", select an additional reference at random, back out
of the dialog, then go back in and unselect the reference you just added. If
that doesn't solve the problem, try to unselect as many of the selected
references as you can (Office may not let you unselect them all), back out
of the dialog, then go back in and reselect the references you just
unselected. (NOTE: write down what the references are before you delete
them, because they'll be in a different order when you go back in)

Yes, disambigulating as VBA.xxxx will work, since Excel no longer has to
look through all of the references.

Comment: Already did that, as per my post stated, and I am still getting errors.

Comment: @MattRidge, the error is not in date, but in format(), as it thinks it's an array, not a function. added more info to the answer