# old vba project code error on Date function call

Tags: ms-access, vba

Just opened an old MS Access 2003 project in order to update a couple of things.  Starting running the program and got the following error (yes different machine with Access 2003 freshly installed) 'Cant find project or library'  The problem seems to revolve around the Date vba function call.  I can:

```
Dim d as Date
d = Date (throws error)
```

and get Date in the dropdown but when I try and use it I get an error.  Before trying a couple of things I was getting the error that the reference to PJCALEND.DLL was missing but before I go and download that file, not sure I trust the various versions I have seen, is there another library that I can use that has this function?  I have looked in the References and nothing is marked as missing.  This seems a little odd to me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date for VBA not working in Excel 2011?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476793/date-for-vba-not-working-in-excel-2011)

Comment: Nope, not the same.  This is Access 2003.  Yes it is a reference issue but this is not being used on a Mac, nor are there any missing references.  I will however try the steps listed and see if they make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Any missing libraries lead to strange errors and mostly these seem to affect the built in VBA functions, for some reason. Calendar controls in particular are a known problem. Check for missing references, ensure that you are using late binding, and, ideally, do not use ActiveX calendar controls.